# Failed boot after changing Nvidia driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, uefi

[CONTEXT BELOW]
I do not get past the Linux Mint logo.
Before the Linux Mint plymouth, and after the constructor's logo, the following can be seen:

> [0.211338] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PC00.X
> HCI.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
> [0.211340] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202107
> 30/psobject-220)
> [0.211342] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PC00.X
> HCI.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
> [0.211344] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202107
> 30/psobject-220)
> [0.211363] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PC00.X
> HCI.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
> [0.211365] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202107
> 30/psobject-220)
> [0.211367] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PC00.X
> HCI.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
> [0.211369] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202107
> 30/psobject-220)
> [0.211388] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PC00.X
> HCI.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
> [0.211390] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202107
> 30/psobject-220)
> [0.211392] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PC00.X
> HCI.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
> [0.211394] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202107
> 30/psobject-220)
> [1.542998]

(Please note I copied those lines letter by letter (from I picture) as I wasn't able to just copy/paste the content. Although copied with great care, there might be typos or copying mistakes.)
And earlier, I didn't get the plymouth, but instead a line stating it had failed to launch plymouth after 120 seconds, etc.

CONTEXT:
I received this freshly built Lenovo laptop yesterday and installed Mint on it. Fractional scaling didn't work, WIFI didn't appear as an option (although that isn't related to the GPU), so I decided to switch the Nvidia driver from open-source to proprietary, as recommended by the Driver Manager GUI. Then, I restarted the laptop as advised, and it occured to me that it simply wouldn't reboot.

SPECS (from Live USB LM's System Info):

> System:
> Kernel: 5.15.0-76-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.8.4
> tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
> Machine:
> Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82YA v: Legion Slim 5 16IRH8 serial: 
> Chassis: type: 10 v: Legion Slim 5 16IRH8 serial: 
> Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: No DPK serial:  UEFI: LENOVO
> v: M2CN29WW date: 09/23/2023
> Battery:
> ID-1: BAT1 charge: 80.0 Wh (100.0%) condition: 80.0/80.0 Wh (100.0%) volts: 17.4 min: 15.4
> model: BYD L22B4PC2 serial:  status: Full
> CPU:
> Info: 14-core (6-mt/8-st) model: 13th Gen Intel Core i7-13700H bits: 64 type: MST AMCP arch: N/A
> rev: 2 cache: L1: 1.2 MiB L2: 11.5 MiB L3: 24 MiB
> Speed (MHz): avg: 1445 high: 3817 min/max: 400/4800:5000:3700 cores: 1: 400 2: 1606 3: 840
> 4: 976 5: 549 6: 2777 7: 400 8: 596 9: 2348 10: 3817 11: 1305 12: 1173 13: 2706 14: 2718 15: 584
> 16: 2717 17: 400 18: 866 19: 953 20: 1171 bogomips: 116736
> Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
> Graphics:
> Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:a7a0
> Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.0
> chip-ID: 10de:28e0
> Device-3: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-7:3
> chip-ID: 04f2:b7b8
> Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting
> gpu: N/A display-ID: :0 screens: 1
> Screen-1: 0 s-res: 2560x1600 s-dpi: 96
> Monitor-1: default res: 2560x1600 size: N/A
> OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 22.2.5 direct render: Yes
> Audio:
> Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
> chip-ID: 8086:51ca
> Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 8
> bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:22be
> Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-76-generic running: yes
> Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
> Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
> Network:
> Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169
> v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 4000 bus-ID: 07:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
> IF: enp7s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 
> Device-2: Realtek vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 3000
> bus-ID: 08:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:c852
> Bluetooth:
> Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-10:5
> chip-ID: 0bda:5852
> Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: 
> Drives:
> Local Storage: total: 491.94 GiB used: 1.6 MiB (0.0%)
> ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVL2512HDJD-00BL2 size: 476.94 GiB speed: 63.2 Gb/s
> lanes: 4 serial:  temp: 38.9 C
> ID-2: /dev/sda type: USB model: N/A size: 15 GiB serial: 
> Partition:
> ID-1: / size: 7.67 GiB used: 90.5 MiB (1.2%) fs: overlay source: ERR-102
> ID-2: /var/log size: 11.89 GiB used: 1.6 MiB (0.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
> Swap:
> Alert: No swap data was found.
> Sensors:
> System Temperatures: cpu: 27.8 C mobo: N/A
> Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
> Repos:
> Packages: apt: 2113
> Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
> 1: deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 21.2 *Victoria* - Release amd64 20230711]/ jammy main
> Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
> 1: deb http: //packages.linuxmint.com victoria main upstream import backport
> 2: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
> 3: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
> 4: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
> 5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
> Info:
> Processes: 366 Uptime: 10m Memory: 15.34 GiB used: 2.05 GiB (13.3%) Init: systemd v: 249
> runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 alt: 11/12 Client: Cinnamon v: 5.8.4 inxi: 3.3.13
> `